# Problem appending string parameter to ADODB command

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-redshift

I'm having trouble appending a string parameter to a command object in VBA. My code will work for all non-string data types in my excel workbook, but throws the following error text when trying to append a string value to a command parameter:

"Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type. Change the cursor type, commit the transaction, or close one of the recordsets."

This code will run successfully if I use the "Usage_ID" command and comment out the "Location" command. Why is this? Why does using a string cause this to fail?

I am inserting data into a Redshift database, and the table columns are set up to use the same type of data VARCHAR(256) that I am using in the query below.

```
Public Sub newInsert()
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    firstRow = 5
    lastRow = 5 '##Just using one row for the test##

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open '##using a DSN file here##

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    conn.BeginTrans

    Dim sql As String
    '## This is the full query I want to execute, 
    '   but it hangs, so I am running with one parameter
    '   at a time for testing. Usage_ID will run with the code below, but 
    '   not location. ##
    'sql = "INSERT INTO new_regions.bw_test (usage_id, location) " _
        '& "VALUES (?, ?)"

    sql = "INSERT INTO new_regions.bw_test (location) " _
         & "VALUES (?)"

    For currentRow = firstRow To lastRow
        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        ' ## The first one will run successfully, not the second ##    
        'cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("usage_id", adBigInt, adParamInput, , sh.Cells(1, "Q").value)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("location", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, "test")

        cmd.Execute

    Next

    conn.CommitTrans

CleanExit:
    conn.Close
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    conn.RollbackTrans
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Transaction was rolled back, no changes were made", vbExclamation
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try changing the length-parameter to the actual size  (from 256 to 4) of the string? Also: Is the database accepting the string `test` multiple times in field `location` and is `Null`  allowed for `usage_id`?

Comment: Thanks. I did just try with 4 rather than 256 as the size parameter, but get the same error. The connection transaction is never executed because of the error, so no, the database doesn't receive any data. Null values are allowed in the table as I just created it for testing purposes and did not place any null restrictions on any of the columns.